# hrefs not working following ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some hrefs originally in an iframe, however, I'm binding the html to AngularJS using the ng-bind-html in an html div. e.g.

```html
<div ng-bind-html="foo"></div>
```

Where foo is the HTML content

The html is from a trusted source and I'm aware of the $sce.trustAsHtml(foo) function, which I am using in the controller class e.g.

```js
$scope.bar = function () {
            if ($scope.foo == null)
                getFoo(Id).then(function (fooData) {
                    $scope.foo = $sce.trustAsHtml(foodata);
                })['catch'](function (reason) {
                    //do something
                });
        };
```

The problem is that in the foo html content I have a few links which are no longer working e.g.

```html
<a href="#MyLink">MyLink</a>
```

And I also have the corresponding html tags e.g.

```html
<a name="MyLink"><a>
```

I did notice that if I edit #MyLink and give it the full URL e.g http://MyWebsite/MyPage#MyLink it works. In fact #/mypage#MyLink is enough. However, sadly it's not possible/reasonable for me to provide the full URLs to the foo html because that's rendered by a different app. These links all work fine if I remove the ng-bind-html attribute but I need that. Also if I cut and paste the html the browser renders into a new page the links work. This is driving me a bit nuts, if anyone has any suggestions to point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

I was reading that in order for ng-functions to work I'd have to use the $complile service, however, these are just standard hrefs so I'm pretty sure I don't need to do that? I'm still relatively new to AngularJS, so I apologize in advance for my naivety...

Comment: You have typo here `<a name="MyLink"><a>`

Answer (score 1):

It work as expected.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/an37vb30/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($sce) {
    this.foo = $sce.trustAsHtml(`<a href="#MyLink">MyLink</a>`);
  });
```

```css
.spacer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-bind-html="vm.foo"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <a name="MyLink">MyLink</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Id like to say thank you to Stepan, your implementation helped me to rule out a few things, I'll vote you up:)

Basically the reason my hrefs were not working following my use of the ng-bind-html attribute was because before the binding they were limited to the scope of the IFrame, which meant that they didn't need the full URL etc.

This left me with two choices, either supply the necessary part of the URL i.e. #/mypage#MyLink, in the application that provides the html i.e. the service layer or don't use the ng-bind-html attribute and stick with the IFrame and find an alternative way to interact with it.

So far I've implemented the first option, which was possible, however, perhaps the second option would lend it's self to better to future changes. I mean if the part of the URL which I'm supplying from the service layer changes in the future it will break these links.